# Disable MouseDragElementBehavior in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, behavior

I have a grid which contains a Rectangle and 2 textblocks. 
The Grid has the `MouseDragElementBehavior`, which I added by dragging the behavior in Expression Blend.

Now in C# I want to be able to disable the `MouseDragElementBehavior` and Re-enable it. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Might be the below url can help [http://stephenchy520.blog.com/2011/08/05/create-customized-component-enable-to-drag-and-acquire-coordinate/](http://stephenchy520.blog.com/2011/08/05/create-customized-component-enable-to-drag-and-acquire-coordinate/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/wp7-drag-drop-example/ have a look at my blog post. 
This is how i access it programmatically

```
BehaviorCollection behaviours = Interaction.GetBehaviors(ball);
if (behaviours.Count > 0 && behaviours[0] is MouseDragElementBehavior)
{
    MouseDragElementBehavior dragBehaviour = behaviours[0] as MouseDragElementBehavior;
}
```

What i tend to now do is not have it in XAML instead i add it at run time.

You can add it when needed and remove it at other times.